# A more appropriate word for "bank"

Tags: single-word-requests

Just like *bank* in "bank of the river", I want a word for an ocean's bank. I don't like "bank of the ocean" -- so is there any better word?

I am writing a literary essay -- and in that article, by "bank of the ocean", I mean happiness compared to an ocean of sorrows and misery.

Comment: Shore, shoreline, beach?

Comment: [Shore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shore) is a distinct possibility. Perhaps *coast*. In this case, some context might help: how do you intend to use the word?

Comment: Having now read your context I would suggest "the safety of the shoreline" or words along those lines.  People who are "trapped" in (or on) the ocean will certainly be heading for shore.

Comment: An island of happiness in an ocean of sorrows and misery?

Answer (score 1):

It's not idiomatic to say the "bank of an ocean", only of a river or stream, but the word is used to describe one aspect of the ocean: "a broad elevation of the sea floor around which the water is relatively shallow but not a hazard to surface navigation."  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bank

Thesaurus.com says, for example: 
http://thesaurus.com/browse/strand?s=b
"strand
"noun
"Definition: sandy area by body of water
"Synonyms: bank, coast, lakeshore, lakeside, littoral, margin, oceanfront, seaboard, seafront, seashore, seaside, shingle, shore, strand , waterfront"

Comment: This is true, but the O.P. wouldn't want to use the word "bank" for when "shore" would be a more suitable word. As a side note, I know some people who work [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Bank).

Comment: From one of my favorite songs: "Let us go to the banks of the ocean". http://chivalry.com/cantaria/lyrics/dutchman.html

Comment: J.R.: I don't understand why sentence 1 is there. It expresses a truism I didn't deny. The 2nd half of the definition I quoted points out how "bank" is used to describe one aspect of the ocean. Therefore, I don't understand why sentence 2 is there.

Comment: ΜετάEd: One instance of a usage doesn't make it idiomatic, does it? I've seen verse and song lyrics that use the structure "for to VERB" (can't find one right now, sorry) and assume that it's merely poetic license. And it's clear that English native-speakers are willing to say anything and claim that it's correct just because they're native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Besides *shore, shoreline, beach, coast* as mentioned in comments, *[plage](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/plage)* is often used, and I have sometimes seen *margin* for land along a coastline.  More specific terms like *landfall*, *bayside,* or *shallows* might work too (the latter for ocean near a shore).

Comment: I've never heard 'plage' used in English, even as a borrowing.

Comment: @Mitch: Both as a Dutch and English speaker, I have only heard it used when referencing a specific _French_ beach (since "plage" is French for "beach"). Similarly, "Riviera" (Italian for "coastline") is still used when referencing either the Italian Riviera or French Riviera.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the *shore*, *beach* and *coast* related suggestions, the term *strand* is sometimes used, but it is not very common in US usage.  [Compact Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strand?region=uk&q=strand) defines it as

> the shore of a sea, lake, or large river

The term *banks* is used to refer to certain sections of ocean that are actually shallow water, such as the [Grand Banks](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/Grand%20Banks) and the Georges Banks.

If you are interested in shallow water areas of ocean near the shore, the term *shoals* might be of interest. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shoals) defines it as

> 1.a stretch of shallow water
>
> 2.a sandbank or rocky area in a stretch of water, esp one that is visible at low water

Comment: Tangentially, "strand" is the Dutch word for "beach".

Answer (score 0):

**harbor**

[*a place of security and comfort (refuge)* (M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbor)

[*a haven; a body of water where ships, boats and barges seek shelter from stormy weather* (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbor)

Answer (score -1):

Beach, shore, shoreline, coast, coastline, embankment, etc., depending on its context and appearance.

In *Daffodils*, Wordsworth said...

> along the margin of a bay